# How to implementation redanduncy on SDN Controller

Tags: python, controller, sdn, opendaylight

I have 3 Opendaylight Controllers and I need to implement VRRP or any redanduncy protocols between them ..  how can i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

For Opendaylight HA, you need to look at the built in features in ODL, using clustering, have a read below:
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/getting-started-guide/clustering.html

Opendaylight has its own datastore and apart from applications, and these information need to be synchronised between the nodes in cluster. In case of failure, the live nodes will cover for the failed node.

Using other protocols such as VRRP, keepalived,etc would help with maintaining a virtual IP between multiple instances, but it wont have any awareness of ODL thus can't operate in the most effective way.